# Fixing/up-rezzing images is easily possible these days in practice. Is there any analogous tool available for low-quality audio?

Tags: audio, noise, audio-processing, deep-learning, superresolution

Tools like waifu2x and Anime4k (for the MPV video player) can already easily de-noise and up-rez low quality images to 4k quality pretty darn well. Similar tools like DLSS and FSR are used for video games.

Are there any analogous tools for low-quality audio? That could properly de-noise it and make it higher quality? For example, a lot of anime from the 2000's have very low quality audio.

I understand that deep audio processing isn't nearly as developed as deep image processing, but I thought I may as well ask.

By the way, I know that a specialized audio engineer could do some combination of filtering and vo-coding to achieve this on a case-by-case basis. That's not what I'm asking for. What I want is a general tool that "just works" without too much tinkering (similar to DLSS, Anime4k, waifu2x, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In think that the best analogy from spatial upsampling may be spectral band replication, where high-frequency components are «guessed» from the low frequency ones.

Like with anime video, one might expect that the better model one have of the signal generation, the better one can repair lost high-frequency components.